# How to fire webhook on particular status change

Tags: jira

Hi I used webhook in JIRA and wrote the JQL query as below,

```
status CHANGED FROM "Waiting Security Approval" TO "Triggered FW commands"
```

When I use webhooks and select issues created,updated,deleted etc webhook is triggered properly and I am getting POST request in my APP.

But I get for all status change, So instead I removed all check mark and added the above mentioned JQL and in that case webhook is not fired.

How can I debug it? JIRA Version what is use is "v7.1.4"

Answer (score 0):

You've misunderstood the JQL part of the Webhook - it's to narrow down the list of Issues for which a Webhook will be emitted when any of the conditions, that you've checked/selected, apply.
So, for example, you can specify (with the JQL) that you only want this Webhook to *apply* for Issues in Project **ABC** or for all Issues where you're the **Assignee** but it will still be only be fired on the events that you've selected in the checkbox groups.

What you need to do is create a Webhook that will fire on event "**Issue** updated" and when you receive it in your application check whether this update transitioned the Issue from the Status you want to the other one. If it did, do something, else ignore the Webhook.

Comment: If I select "Issue updated" then I get POST data with all updates not filtering on my JQL. Any status change the trigger is done

Comment: Ok it is happening like this, If any issue has the state change of above then webhook is triggered. Eg: step 1,2 ,3 trigger will not happen as the state is still not as mentioned in JQL but for state 4,5,6 webhook is triggered. So it means like all updates after the state change are getting triggered.   @rorschach Do you have any Idea how to handle this ?

Comment: Same thing as @NaggappanRamukannan describes above in the comments happens to me too here in Feb 2023. So I guess that either I'm doing something wrong or the problem hasn't been fixed in over 5 years. Have anyone found a way to work around that beside disabling event triggering and linking the webhook to a workflow transition?